# while loop in sybase ASE

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I am using the below sybase version of
 Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 16375/P/NT (IX86)/Windows 2003/ase1503/2670/32-bit/OPT/Mon Nov 17 17:49:12 2008

Trying to work upon a simple while loop, however it runs only once. Using interactive sql GUI to run it.

```
declare @i int, @j int
    set @i=1
    set @j=5
    while(@i<=@j)
    begin
    select '1'
    set @i=@i+1
    end
```

Comment: can someone help me with this...

Comment: reinstalled the client and got it working... not sure what went wrong with existing installation.